# Custom Control - Give animation image as xml

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls

We need to develop a valve custom control which will animate open/close position of a valve baseon on the value of an OPC tag. 
For Eg: if the value of Valve Tag is 1, Draw the valve in open position. if the value of Valve Tag is 0, Draw the valve in close position. The control will expose a property to give the TAG name.

There are several ways in which the valve can be animated. So we need to let the application using the control to speciy the image to draw for open valve/close position. Is it possible to give the image to draw as a xaml item Instead of giving the image as a file (Eg:png or jpg)?

What things should I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may fill the control area with different [DrawingBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingbrush.aspx) instances, depending on its state. Those brushes might be defined in the control's Resources.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DrawingBrush x:Key="valveOpen">
        ...
    </DrawingBrush>
    <DrawingBrush x:Key="valveClosed">
        ...
    </DrawingBrush>
</UserControl.Resources>
<!-- change Background when the state changes -->
<Grid x:Name="root" Background="{StaticResource valveOpen}">
    ...
</Grid>
```